# Querying n:m-Relationships with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4.3

I got a n:m-Relationship with these three tables:

[image: Database Model]

Now I want to query all `Activities`, that have a list of selected `Characteristics` attached.

My query:

```
e.QueryableSource = _dataContext.Activities.Where(ac => 
                ac.UserId == _userId && 
                ac.ResubmissionDate <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(_to) && 
                ac.Priority <= (int)_prio && 
                ac.CompletedDate == null && 
                ac.Characteristics.Contains(CharacFilter));
```

That sadly doesn't work, as `ac.Characteristics.Contains()` expects items of type `ActivityCharacteristics`, and not a type of `Characteristic`

How can I achieve that?

A side node: I don't want an exclusive filtering, say when I specify three characteristics in `CharacFilter`, I want to query every activity that may have one of these three characteristics (not necessarily all of them) attached.

Edit:
`CharacFilter` is a `private IEnumerable<int> CharacFilter { get; set; }` 
It is being filled from a view where I select those characteristics and hold them in the View-Variable `public List<Characteristic> SelectedCharacteristics { get; set; }`

My assignment:

```
        var view = new AssignCharacteristicsView();
        view.ShowDialog();

        if (view.SelectedCharacteristics != null)
        {
            CharacFilter = view.SelectedCharacteristics.Select(cf => cf.Id);
        }
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `CharacFilter` is an `IEnumerable<Characteristics>`, you could try:

```
IEnumerable<int> charaFilters = CharacFilter.Select(cf => cf.Id);

e.QueryableSource = _dataContext.Activities.Where(ac => 
    ac.UserId == _userId && 
    ac.ResubmissionDate <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(_to) && 
    ac.Priority <= (int)_prio && 
    ac.CompletedDate == null &&
    ac.Characteristics.Any(acc => characFilters.Contains(acc.CharacteristicId)));
```

(`acc` is of type `ActivityCharacteristics`.)

And `Activity.Characteristics` should really have the name `Activity.ActivityCharacteristics` like you named it in the `Characteristics` entity. It's pretty confusing otherwise.

**Edit**

About your exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable´1'

If `CharacFilter` is `null` you will indeed get this exception because `null` is a constant value that EF is unable to create. It won't throw a `NullReferenceException` because you are using `CharacFilter` in an expression. According to your edited code in the question `CharacFilter` could be `null` if `view.SelectedCharacteristics` is `null`.

To solve the problem you have to catch the `null` case depending on if `view.SelectedCharacteristics == null` means *all* characteristics or *none* in your application. If it means *none* I would suggest to instantiate an empty list:

```
if (view.SelectedCharacteristics != null)
{
    CharacFilter = view.SelectedCharacteristics.Select(cf => cf.Id);
}
else
{
    CharacFilter = new List<int>();
}
```

If it means *all* characteristics you could try:

```
// ...
ac.Characteristics.Any(acc => (characFilters != null
    ? characFilters.Contains(acc.CharacteristicId)
    : true)));
```

**Edit 2**

Last option throws the same exception (not surprising because to compare `CharacFilter` with `null` a constant value must be created again). Alternative (just omit the last `Where` clause if `CharacFilter` is `null`):

```
ObjectQuery<Activity> query = _dataContext.Activities.Where(ac => 
    ac.UserId == _userId && 
    ac.ResubmissionDate <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(_to) && 
    ac.Priority <= (int)_prio && 
    ac.CompletedDate == null);

if (characFilters != null)
{
    query = query.Where(ac => ac.Characteristics
                     .Any(acc => characFilters.Contains(acc.CharacteristicId)));
}

e.QueryableSource = query;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've renamed it to `Activity.ActivityCharacteristics` again. Since `characFilter` is of type `IEnumerable<Characteristics>` and not of `IEnumerable<int>`, I've changed the last line like this: `ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any(acc => CharacFilter.Contains(acc.Characteristic)));`

Comment: Okay, I've run the code and getting the following exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'.`

Comment: @SeToY: That's because of your change. Why don't you use my first line?

Comment: No, it even happens without my change and your original query on the int-Values, but says `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.` instead.

Comment: @SeToY: I've tested it and it works. There must be something different. If I use your code I don't get the exception "*Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1'*" but instead "*Unable to create a constant value of type 'Characteristics'*" which is what I would expect. We are probably not talking about the same code. The `CharacFilter` in your question is what exactly? A `List<Characteristics>`?

Comment: `CharacFilter` is a `private IEnumerable<int> CharacFilter { get; set; }`, being filled like this: `CharacFilter = SelectedCharacteristics.Select(cf => cf.Id);` and queried like this: `(ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any(acc => CharacFilter.Contains(acc.CharacteristicId) || !ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any()))`

Comment: Maybe I need to add that no exception is actually being thrown but the query yields no results and contains this error message instead of "real" entities or objects.

Comment: @SeToY: Are you sure that the single closing bracket before the `||` is correct? It compiles but the logic is strange. I would expect two closing brackets after `Contains` and one less at the end.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, of course. I've changed that, but it still shows the same error: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenannt9sxvy.png

Comment: @SeToY: Can you try to replace `Any(acc => CharacFilters.Contains...)` by `Any(acc => (new List<int> { 1, 2 }).Contains...)`. It is EF 4.0, right? Not EF 1 in .NET 3.5?

Comment: It is indeed EF4.0, but how should I merge `new List<int> { 1, 2 }` with my list `IEnumerable<int> CharacFilter` that's already present?

Comment: @SeToY: Don't merge, replace it just for a test. I want to know if `Characfilters` is causing the exception. Also could you call `e.QueryableSource.ToList()` after you have build the query to execute it (maybe in a try-catch block to see if you get the same exception).

Comment: `e.QueryableSource` does not contain a definition for `ToList`. `(ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any(acc => (new List<int> { 1, 2 }).Contains(acc.CharacteristicId)) || !ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any())` works flawlessly.

Comment: @SeToY: OK, can you then show `CharacFilters` (type and how you fill it) *exactly* in your question (edit question). There must be the problem. (I've googled that `QueryableSource` is a DevExpress thing and a non-generic `IQueryable`, there is indeed no `ToList`. You could save the query into the temporary variable (just use `var`) and then call `ToList()` on that variable.)

Comment: I've edited the question and added everything I assume you'll need to know. If something's missing, please tell me. `QueryableSource` is a property from DevExpress's `LinqInstantFeedbackSource` for the DXGrid. Saving the query into a variable and calling `ToList()` on it yields the same results: An exception `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`. I've also edited the tags to match the EntityFramework version.

Comment: @SeToY: I've edited my answer, hopefully that's it :) At least I could reproduce your error now.

Comment: `ac.ActivityCharacteristics.Any(acc => (CharacFilter != null ? CharacFilter.Contains(acc.CharacteristicId) : true)));` still throws this exception :P I want to query all activities that have at least one of the characteristics assigned, if `CharacFilter` is null, it should display ALL activities, even without characteristics attached

Comment: This does not throw an exception, but does not work with the `LinqInstantFeedbackSource` of DevExpress... The query needs to be assigned upon start and can't be changed during the runtime, thus never passes `if (CharacFilter != null)` because it's only being run on startup.

Comment: @SeToY: O dear, that's evil. I might be then that it's not possible what you are trying to achieve. I have no idea how to solve the problem at this point now. Perhaps ask a new question which focusses at this point specifically (your last comment), maybe someone else has an idea. (Or DevExpress support as a last reserve.)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I finally managed to get it working by restructuring a small part of my application. Nevertheless your second edit is working with my recent modifications and you have helped me a lot. You're an amazing person. Thank you.